# How can I describe the loading effect of an ohmmeter?

Tags: measurement, instrumentation, ohmmeter, loading-effect, resistance-measurement

How can I describe the loading effect in an ohmmeter? I've been given an assignment with this question, and I tried to look it up on the internet but could find no other material apart from loading effect of a voltmeter and an ammeter.

How does it take affect the resistance measurement for an ohmmeter? The mathematical formulation or any relevant expressions might help.

Comment: Do you understand how an ohmmeter works?

Comment: Are you sure if it's ohmmeter? I've never heard of loading effect or similar concerns for an ohmmeter or resistance measurement *(AFAIK, meter loading is meaningful for current and voltage measurements)*. You normally take resistance measurements in an unpowered circuit, so why/how would loading be possible?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I know right?! We've got a pretty eccentric professor, and so are his assignments :)
I guess I should take the liberty and explain about the effect in a voltmeter and an ammeter instead.

Comment: Analog or Digital?  Single resistor or a resistor in a circuit?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Let's say Analog and the resistor is not in a circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohmmeters aren't passive things that "load" a circuit like ammeters or voltmeters.  Instead, they have to actively measure the component under test.

Ultimately, the equation is simply R = V/I.

The ohmmeter will use its battery to apply a known voltage across the component under test, and then measure the current that flows.  Alternatively, it can use a built-in constant current source to push a current through the component, and measure what voltage that produces.

Answer (score 0):

### Teaching through humor

This is a "trap" set by your eccentric professor. Expect his next question to be, "What are the capabilities of the resistor to power sources?" :-) But I am also a fan of this kind of teaching with (a little) humor because otherwise there is a danger that students will fall asleep during the lecture :-)

### The most basic electrical circuit

It was a joke, but here is a more serious explanation. To have a useful circuit (closed circuit) you need at least two elements - one (the *source*) to produce current, voltage or both, the other (the *load*) to consume them.

So the source is loaded by the resistor...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDGoS3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

... and the resistor is driven by the source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frbEFw.png)</sup>

### What an ohmmeter is

Simply put, an ohmmeter is a combination of two elements - a ***source*** of one electrical quantity (voltage or current) and a ***measuring device*** of the other quantity (current or voltage).

**19th century:** The first arrangement - a voltage source and ammeter connected in series - was used in the 19th century when they had poor voltmeters but good ammeters (galvanometers). So then an ohmmeter was a “constant voltage source with an indicated current through it”.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzHulI.png)</sup>

The problem with these ohmmeters was that they were non-linear because the unknown quantity - the resistance, was in the denominator, and the current represents the resistance (I = V/R). We can see it in the graph below if we sweep Rx (run *DC Sweep Simulation*).

[image: STEP 2.1a]

Note that the resistance begins changing not from zero but from some small value (10 Ω) to limit the current. This means that in the practical circuit, we have to insert such a resistor in series.

To linearize the reading, they made the ohmmeter scales "inversely non-linear". We can mimic it here by calculating the resistance (R = V/I) in the graph below.

[image: STEP 2.1b]

**21st century:** The second arrangement - current source and voltmeter in parallel, is used today when we have bad ammeters but good voltmeters (ADC). So now an ohmmeter is a “constant current source with an indicated voltage across it”.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cijh.png)</sup>

These ohmmeters are now linear because the division is replaced by multiplication and the voltage represents the resistance (V = I.R). We can see it in the graph below if we sweep Rx with *DC Sweep Simulation*.

[image: STEP 2.2a]

The calculated resistance is the same as above.

[image: STEP 2.2b]

### Looking for a truth in eccentricity

Let's try to find some useful application of the eccentric professor's question anyway. For example, imagine that the internal resistance of factory-produced batteries needs to be measured. What would then be the ohmmeter with which we will measure it? Does it need its own battery? Obviously not because the measurement object has a built-in voltage source. So in this case the ohmmeter would just be an ammeter (load) and then the question, "What is its loading effect?" would make some sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frI9b0.png)</sup>